# How can I fix this error about plugin and sdk version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

This happens when i try to run the android app
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y8Gy.png)
This is the build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'





ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'material-hijri-calendarview'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.eltohamy'
    libraryName = 'material-hijri-calendarview'
    artifact = 'material-hijri-calendarview'

    libraryDescription = 'A Material design back port of Android\'s Hijri CalendarView. The goal is to have a Material look and feel, rather than 100% parity with the platform\'s implementation.'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview'
    gitUrl = 'hhttps://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.1.2'

    developerId = 'eltohamy'
    developerName = 'El-Tohamy Allam'
    developerEmail = 'tohamy_allam@yahoo.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.github.msarhan', name: 'ummalqura-calendar', version: '1.1.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

}
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

Tried removing the maven plugin as this is the most recommended answer on the internet and still didn't work and my sdkVersion i am using is 34

Answer (score 0):

try changing below code with your existing code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'



ext {

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.eltohamy'
    libraryName = 'material-hijri-calendarview'
    artifact = 'material-hijri-calendarview'

    libraryDescription = 'A Material design back port of Android\'s Hijri CalendarView. The goal is to have a Material look and feel, rather than 100% parity with the platform\'s implementation.'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview'
    gitUrl = 'hhttps://github.com/eltohamy/material-hijri-calendarview.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.1.2'

    developerId = 'eltohamy'
    developerName = 'El-Tohamy Allam'
    developerEmail = 'tohamy_allam@yahoo.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.github.msarhan', name: 'ummalqura-calendar', version: '1.1.9'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'

}
```

In this, i have removed bintry details and two lines from bottoms which is related to bintry library

Because it throughs issue on updating gradle to newest android version

i was having same issue so after removing it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community thank you. i'll carefull in future while writing answers.